# ASIHTTPRequest setDidFailSelector not called

Tags: ios, authentication, asihttprequest

Hi I have an app using `ASIHTTPRequest` to log-in to a web server. When the username and password are both correct, `loginRequestFinished` is called. However, When the log-in credentials are incorrect, neither the `loginRequestFinished` nor the `loginRequestFailed` are called.

I tried to get around this by implementing an `NSTimer` so that it will give an error message and cancel the request after 60s. However it looks like the request has already been `dealloc` by then (I found this weird as the loading indicator in the status bar is still spinning).

**This is the error I got:**

```
-[__NSCFTimer cancel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84f0720
(lldb)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void) login 
{    
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/local_login.html", self.serverIP];

    ASIHTTPRequest *theRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [theRequest setDelegate:self];
    [theRequest setUsername:username];
    [theRequest setPassword:password];
    [theRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(loginRequestFinished:)];
    [theRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(loginRequestFailed:)];
    [theRequest startAsynchronous];
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f
                                                        target:self
                                             selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:NO];
}
- (void)timerFired:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    UIAlertView *warning = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]autorelease];
    [warning show];
    [request cancel];
    [request release];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

**Update:**
I checked the server log. If I got the password or username incorrect, my app is sending login request to the server every second until I quit the iPhone Simulator.

```
2013-09-11 16:22:02.187 /local_login.html 401 91ms 0kb EC 1.0.1 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 6.1; en_US)
  150.101.105.182 - - [11/Sep/2013:16:22:02 -0700] "GET /local_login.html HTTP/1.1" 401 404 - "EC 1.0.1 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 6.1; en_US)" "xyz.appspot.com" ms=91 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000045 app_engine_release=1.8.4 instance=00c71b118abd13a90c30bcf64033c95172a494
2013-09-11 16:22:01.754 /local_login.html 401 29ms 0kb EC 1.0.1 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 6.1; en_US)
  150.101.105.182 - - [11/Sep/2013:16:22:01 -0700] "GET /local_login.html HTTP/1.1" 401 404 - "EC 1.0.1 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 6.1; en_US)" "xyz.appspot.com" ms=30 cpu_ms=21 cpm_usd=0.000045 app_engine_release=1.8.4 instance=00c71b118abd13a90c30bcf64033c95172a494
(More Similar log events)
```

Thanks all. Issue have been resolved. It is the way that I passed in the ASIHTTPRequest to myTimer. I realized I have to use userInfo to passed in theRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the login method set the UserInfo for the timer. like below

```
 ASIHTTPRequest *theRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];



myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f
                                                        target:self
                                             selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                      userInfo:theRequest
                                                       repeats:NO];
```

why are you invalidating the timer if repeats:NO. If you set repeats to NO timer will be invalidated automatically.

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    ///[myTimer invalidate];  /// coment this. it will work.

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = (ASIHTTPRequest *)[timer userInfo];
    UIAlertView *warning = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]autorelease];
    [warning show];
    [request cancel]; 
    ///[request release]; ///request is an autorelease object
}
```

If you do this it should work properly.

Also in the see the argument in the method timerFired: timer is the argument that is passed, whenever the timerFired: method is invoked by the timer.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after commenting the `[myTimer invalidate];` line

Comment: Thanks you re right. it is the argument hasn't been passed in causing the problem. I should use the userInfo to pass in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your login server may throw authentication challenge,Does it?

Why not use `[theRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60];` instead of complexing with the timers - Crash issue is coz of timers.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the setTimeOutSeconds; however, the loading indicator in the status bar does not stop spinning still.

Comment: Can you make a synchronous call? [theRequest startSynchronous];